# jquery function is not executed. What I am missing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
@model CETAPPSUGG.Models.CustomAppViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UPLOAD YOUR APPLICATION";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var locationFile;

        $('#txtUploadFile').on('change', function (e) {
            alert('tta"');
            var files = e.target.files;
            //var myID = 3; //uncomment this to make sure the ajax URL works
            if (files.length > 0) {
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var data = new FormData();
                    for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                        data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
                        alert('tta"');

                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/Apps/UploadHomeReport',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: data,
                        success: function (result) {
                            locationFile = result;
                            $('#hat').val(result);

                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                            alert('errrrror"');

                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
                }   }

        });


        function GetCity(_stateId) {
            alert("It called");

            var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
            $("#ddlcity").html(procemessage).show();
            var url = "/Home/GetCityByStaeId/";

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { stateid: _stateId },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Sub Category</option>";
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#ddlcity").html(markup).show();
                },
                error: function (reponse) {
                    alert("error : " + reponse);
                }
            });

        }


    });


</script>


<div class="col-md-12">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AppPost", "Apps", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Apps.AppFileLocation, new { id = "hat" });


    <table class="table" width="200">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Application Name: </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apps.AppName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apps.AppName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Application Description: </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apps.AppDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apps.AppDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Select Category: </td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFlavorId, Model.FlavorItems) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apps.Categories.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Sub Category: </td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFlavorSubCategoryId, Model.FlavorSubCategoryItems)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apps.SubCatagories.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Upload Picture: </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.icon, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.icon, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select your Application from Computer: </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="Upload From Computer" id="txtUploadFile" class="makethispretty" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td class="text-primary">Click Create to Submit</td>

                <td><input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <select id="deneme" onchange="javascript:GetCity(this.value);"> <option value="1">Opsiyon1 </option>
    <option value="2">Opsiyon2</option></select>
    <select id="ddlcity" name="ddlcity" style="width: 200px"></select>


}

    </div>
```

function GetCity(_stateId) is not executed. The other functions for txupload file and ajax works fine but getCity function do not work. I even cannot see the alert?. What I am missing. Is there any confusion for the browser. Thank you

Comment: because getCity is not global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `onclick` event handler to the `ValidationMessageFor`. Presumably, you mean to add it to the `DropdownListFor`?

Also, the function `GetCity` is defined inside the `DOMReady` scope. It is not available in the global context where the `onclick` handler is executed. You'll need to move it outside of `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.